# iOS Firefox XMLHttpRequest wrong response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I have a function that send a XMLHttpRequest GET to retrieve JSON from my backend.

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
    {
        applicationUtil.showLoader(false);
        if(handler != null)
        {
            alert(xhttp.responseText);
            if(xhttp.responseText != "" && this.getResponseHeader('content-type') == "application/json")
            {
                handler(JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText), false);
            }
            else
            {
                handler("", true);
            }
        }
    }
}

xhttp.open("GET", "../../csp/healthshare/hsanalytics/Custom.AMY.REST.Session.cls?CacheUserName="+ username +"&CachePassword="+ password, true);
xhttp.send(null);
```

Now, this function works 100% on any browser on any device, accept iOS Firefox. I have tried going the jQuery route, same results:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "../../csp/healthshare/hsanalytics/Custom.AMY.REST.Session.cls?CacheUserName="+ username +"&CachePassword="+ password,
      accepts:"application/json",
      cache: false,
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: "json",
      username: username,
      password: password,
      error: function(event)
      {
          handler("", true);
      },
      success: function(data, status)
      {
          handler(data, false);
      } 
});
```

I have spent hours researching the topic, but I have not been able to find any articles specific to my problem.

Comment: Is there a specific problem with the jQuery version? Have you checked the console for errors? You should also remove the `crossDomain`, `username` and `password` properties.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the console, and initially I only had the url, accepts, error and success attributes and this did not make any difference.

Comment: Then can you describe what you mean by 'wrong response'.

Comment: is `handler` called?

Comment: @rory, I have not been able to see what the response is on the device, as I don't know of a way to check the network on the phone, in Firefox. but desktop response is always a JSON response if the authentication was successful, and if the login was successful, I would get an HTML page as a response, which is the back end's internal login page.

Comment: @Jaromanda X, it does reach that point yes, to be more specific, on Firefox mobile, the "error" function always gets called. Even though the login credentials were correct.

Comment: from your code I see you do nothing with the error - may be useful to log it or display it or something ... error messages can usually shed some light on the error ... debugging 101

Comment: @Jaromanda X, I feel pretty stupid now, for some reason I thought the error attribute could only accept a function with event as a parameter, only saw now that it can give you three parameters,  jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown. Will check out what it says, but it seems to be a JSON parse issue.

Comment: you can debug the non jquery version just as easy, using `onload` / `onerror` instead of the antiquated `onreadystatechange`

Comment: Checking the alerts I added, the error seems to be that the response from the server is wrong, as it's sending HTML even if the authentication was successful, is there anything else from a front-end perspective that I could be doing wrong or that the server could be interpreting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers are very finicky when it comes to headers.. Have you tried to send basic authorization? Including username and password..

e.g)

```
{
"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
},
```

Give it a go and see :)